# Interval of Existence for initial value problem: $\dot x = x^2$, $x(0) = x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am currently reading through a chapter of a book called 'Differential Dynamical Systems' by James D. Meiss and the initial value problem shown in the title is an example given in Chapter 3 (numbered 3.22) which is solved by separation of variables, giving the solution $x(t)=\frac{x_0}{1-x_0t}$. This isn't hard but then the author explains that the interval of existence is $t \in (-\infty, \frac{1}{x_0})$ for positive $x_0$. I don't understand why the solution does not exist $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{\frac{1}{x_0}\}$. When you differentiate at any point not equal to $t=\frac{1}{x_0}$, you get $\dot x=\frac{{x_0}^2}{(1-x_0t)^2}=x^2$ so I'm not sure if maybe I don't fully understand what is meant by 'interval of existence' or if there's something else that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maximal solutions of an ODE $\begin{cases}y'=F(t,y)\\ y(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}$ ($F:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^d\to \Bbb R^d$) are maximal in the set of partial functions $g:I\to\Bbb R^d$ such that $I$ is an open interval containing $t_0$, $g'(t)=F(t,g(t))$ for all $t$ and $g(t_0)=x_0$; the ordering is inclusion-extension.

The reason for this is that, in a way, when you pass from a connected component of the domain to the other, you end up losing all relation with the previous one. More concretely, there are not just one, but infinitely many solutions $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{\frac1{t_0}\}\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(0)=x_0$. To name a few: $$f(t)=\frac{x_0}{1-x_0t}\\ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x_0}{1-x_0t}&\text{if }t<\frac1{t_0}\\ \frac{x_0+1}{1-(x_0+1)t}&\text{if }t>\frac1{t_0}\end{cases}\\ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x_0}{1-x_0t}&\text{if }t<\frac1{t_0}\\ \frac{x_0+2}{1-(x_0+2)t}&\text{if }t>\frac1{t_0}\end{cases}\\\vdots$$
and I could go on. This would make the correspendence (or, more appropriately, *a* correspondence) sending every $(t_0,x_0)$ to a maximal solution with inital data $y(t_0)=x_0$ quite more cumbersome, all the more if you want to guarantee that two maximal solutions coincide if and only if they have the same value at some point.